# how to convert an input stream to a java object

Tags: java

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(reg_be);
oos.flush();
oos.close();

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

This code convert Java `Object` to `InputStream` and how can I convert `InputStream` to an `Object`?  I need to convert my `Object` to an `InputStream` then I pass it and I want to get my `Object` back.

Comment: ObjectInputStream seems REALLY obvious.

Answer (score 18):

In `try` block you should write:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
Object object = ois.readObject();
```

`ObjectInputStream` is initialized with another stream, e.g. `BufferedInputStream` or your input stream `is`.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos); oos.writeObject(reg_be); oos.flush(); oos.close(); InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()); this code showing exception java.io.NotSerializableException: why?

Comment: Because the class of the object (`reg_be`) you are serializing/deserializing must implement `Serializable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
Object object = ois.readObject();
```

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
 oos.writeObject(reg_be);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());  this code showing exception   java.io.NotSerializableException:  why?

Comment: Because your class doesn't `implement Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
ObjectInputStream  ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
Object obj = ois .readObject();
```

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos); oos.writeObject(reg_be); oos.flush(); oos.close(); InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()); this code showing exception java.io.NotSerializableException: why?

Comment: Why posting a completely same answer like previous two?

Comment: Does you class implement Serializable? It should or else you will get that exception. Class whose object you are transferring in your I/O streams.

Comment: @darijan did not see the previous two.

Comment: ok i have to serialize my object... ok ill do. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
Object object = ois.readObject();
```

As mentioned by @darijan is working fine.
But again we need to do try, catch block for that code, & for blank input stream it will give EOF (End Of File) related error.

So, I am converting it to a string. Then if the string is not empty or null, then only I am converting it to Object using ObjectMapper

Although it's not an efficient approach, I don't need to worry about try-catch, null handling also is done in a string instead of the input stream

```
String responseStr = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Object object = null;
// is not null or whitespace consisted string
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(response)) {
    object = getJsonFromString(response);
}


// below codes are already used in project (Util classes)
private Object getJsonFromString(String jsonStr) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(jsonStr)) {
        return new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();

    Map<Object, Object> obj = null;
    try {
        obj = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<Map<Object, Object>>() {
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to parse JSON : {}",e)
    }
    return obj;
}
private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
    return objectMapper;
}
```